# MySQL statement won't work with a certain variable name

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a page that gets a couple of variables from the url through a php GET method. The address would be

```
sampledomain.com/sample.php?id=11&in=16&lang=1
```

Then I use `$in = $_GET['in'];` and `$id =$_GET['id'];` to get the values.

Now, I have a MySQL statement like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('$in', '$some_variable') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

It just doesn't work even though the `$in` value is correct (I checked that). What's really strange is, when I put `$id` (or any numeric value) instead of `$in`, it inserts it! Both $id and `$in` are numeric, out of desperation I tried using `$in_num = intval($in)` and then inserting `$in_num` but no luck. No error is thrown.

The `$some_variable` part is irrelevant to this problem, the statement behaves the same with or without it.

This is a real conundrum for me, why would the statement work for one variable but not the other?

Comment: have you tried executing the failing query directly on the database? see what error message you get

Comment: die isn't saying anything. the query works in the database directly, the problem is somehow with the variable.

Comment: but it should work. And also in your example the $some_variable, is it declared?

Comment: I know it should work, that's why I'm here:) $some_variable is fine. Either way, when I write the statement to just update column1 with $in, it still doesn't work. I'm completely confused, I've been staring at this for 2 hours.

Comment: If this is not working, die will die. So, what is not working?

Comment: Again, it works when I put $id instead of $in. In my example, $id is 11 and $in is 16. MySQL doesn't throw any error either way, it just inserts it in one case but not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah, I have ['in'] on the page, I mistyped it here.

that's the problem.
the only your problem.

it is obvious that nothing mysterious in a variable name, **expecially** when this variable gets interpolated and do not interfere with SQL at all.
thus, the only possible reason left - the typo again.
**And as you fail to post the correct code here, it is become impossible to even find that typo for you.**  You have to do it yourself.

The only thing you can do to help yourself is to print out each interpolated variables and compare them.

Instead of silly one-liner a sane programmer would separate his code into several lines for the better readability/maintainability:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('$in', '$some_variable')";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
```

thus you can comment out the actual query execution and print the query out instead, for the debugging purposes. 
And thus you'll be able to see yourself, if there is any difference in a variable names.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('$in', '$some_variable')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('$id', '$some_variable')";
var_dump($sql1==$sql2,$sql1,$sql2);
```

Comment: First of all, I typed everything out, several times. $in types out as 16. $id types out as 11. If die(mysql_error()) doesn't show anything, why would trigger_error do any better? There is NO typo in the code. The only typo here was a forgotten '. The mysql statement is copy-pasted. My question here is simple: if $in is 16 and $id is 11, and both variables are created the same way, why would the same query possibly work with one but not the other? I'm not looking for basic syntax tips and I'm definitely not looking for someone to question my sanity.

Comment: I'm not looking for such a long comments. Just an output of the code I posted here is enough (assuming you'll assign the same number to the variables).

Comment: bool(false) string(61) "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('16', '81')" string(61) "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('11', '81')" - that's what var_dump prints out

Comment: The trigger_error(...) code doesn't print out anything. And mysql_query($sql) doesn't insert anything into the DB.

Comment: bool(true) string(61) "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('16', '81')" string(61) "INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values ('16', '81')"

Comment: ^^ in this case I had sample.php?id=16&in=16&lang=1 in the address.

Comment: look, these queries are equal (`bool(true)` proves that). thus there is no difference, what variable to use. you have to look for another reason. Let me suggest a typo or some mistake of the sort, like if you are editing one file and running another one. Also try to run these queries with both numbers hardcoded . I doubt the number can be an issue but just to be sure.

Comment: There is only one file. I've tried hardcoding numbers, it inserts them fine. The two queries are equal, but when I run both, sql2 works but sql1 doesn't. I know this doesn't make any sense, that's why I'm here looking for help. I've gone through every possible mistake and blunder I can think off, I've tried setting $in=16; instead of $in=$_GET['in'];, I've tried renaming it, saving it in a different variable, nothing works.

Comment: In fact, now that I look at it, it doesn't accept anything EXCEPT for $id. Even when I set $trythis=16; and then put $trythis instead of $in, it won't work.

Comment: You have to trust your eyes and start looking for some typo instead of some mysterious reason. There are none.

Answer (score -3):

first of all $in = $_GET[in']; has to be $in = $_GET['in']; you forgot a quote, and also in php when you do '$in' the result will be (STRING) $in but when you put "$in" then you will get the value of the variable.
Secondly try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tagovi_rel (column1, column2) values (".$in.", ".$some_variable.") ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yeah, I have ['in'] on the page, I mistyped it here. Writing the variables like that doesn't help, in fact it was like that originally and it didn't work. As I said, the statement works when I put $id instead of $in. When I print them out $id is, for example, 11 and $in is 16. What could be wrong?